# Eventhandler-function can't use other (helper)functions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cytoscape.js

Im trying to build an app with Cytoscape.js and Angular2+.
The Core part take place in a single service (cy.service).
I add all Eventlisteners in a single function and call it after the cy init.

eg:

```
initEventlisteners(){
  cy.on('tap', this.handler);
  cy.on(...);
  ...
}

handler(event: any){
 console.log('something');
}
```

If I wrap console.log in a helper-function like that:

```
helper(){
 console.log('something');
)
```

And use it in the handler-function

```
handler(event:any){
 this.helper();
}
```

It calls: helper() is not a function.
Thats a big problem that a cant use other functions inside the handler.
Any ideas how to solve that problem ?

Comment: you should register those events using `HostListeners` in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because with binding like this `cy.on('tap', this.handler);` you are loosing scope of variable. You should use it in this way `cy.on('tap', (event) => { this.handler(event) });` (if it's passing any `event` object) or `cy.on('tap', this.handler.bind(this));`.

The frist approach with `() => { }` is called `arrow function`, which preserve current scope of variables. It's a new feature of `ES6` specification. However you don't have to be afraid, angular compiler will convert it to backward compatible to `ES5`.

The second approach `.bind(this)` just simply binding this method to current scope where it's was called.

Comment: One additional question: How can I explain that its possible to use normal variables in this-scope without .bind(this) ?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated,look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762505/4700863) and answers below, maybe you will find answers.